# Explain mock() in context to cmocka unit testing framework

Tags: c, unit-testing

I am learning cmocka unit testing framework. I am a bit puzzled at use of mock() function. Can somebody explain it clearly why and how it is used with suitable examples? Also please explain when it should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read https://lwn.net/Articles/558106/ to understand the mock() feature.

Comment: It would have been better to actually post an answer here. Just plain links are discouraged, in case of link rot. Copy/pasting a few examples from that page is the preferred way to do it.